# Sending a string and a model in Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I  have the following URL.Action in my cshtml:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ShowStudent", "Student", new { studentCode = item.StudentCode, newPrivateStudent = Model.PrivateStudent })">
             <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
</a>
```

The action in my controller is:

```
 public ActionResult ShowCShowStudentlient(studentCode studentCode , PrivateStudentModel newPrivateStudent )
    { *some actions*}
```

When the action is hit in the controller the newPrivateStudent is set as null.

Any idea why?
The newPrivateStudent properties are set as hidden in the cshtml.

Comment: You cannot send a complex object like that (look at the url you are generating to understand). And why would you want to send `Model.PrivateStudent` anyway - you already know what it is on the server. And what do your hidden inputs have to do with it (they are not sent in a link)

Comment: Nope I do not have the model values on the server and the values.  I was just mentionning where the values of the model are coming from: they are set as hidden in the cshtml.

Comment: What? Your hidden inputs are not send in a link! (you could only send those to the controller if you where posting a form to your GET method (which would be pointless since you would then only post the ID of `PrivateStudentModel`)

Comment: And your `studentCode ClientCode` parameter makes no sense, but I assume its really `string studentCode`?

Comment: How can I do to send both the ID and the Model to the controller then?

Comment: studentCode ClientCode was just typo error

Comment: You would not send the model - that makes no sense. You just send the ID of `PrivateStudentModel`

Comment: No.  The Id is that of an existing object and the model is not an object yet created in the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179314/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tabby).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should look at this `@Url.Action` helper:

```
@Url.Action("ShowStudent", "Student", new { studentCode = item.StudentCode, newPrivateStudent = Model.PrivateStudent })
```

The helper above will generate URL with query string like the following example (already tested):

```
<a href="/Student/ShowStudent?studentCode=XXX&newPrivateStudent=ProjectNamespace.Models.PrivateStudent">...</a>
```

As you see at the last parameter (`newPrivateStudent`), instead of adding contents of the complex object, the helper implicitly calls `ToString()` which returns fully-qualified name of that object (and subsequently `newPrivateStudent` has null value in action method). Hence, the proper way to do so is using AJAX callback to post corresponding key together with model contents to controller action and sends back its response as partial view to target DOM element.

Here is an example for sending model contents inside a form with AJAX postback (assumed using HTML helpers to generate input elements):

```
$('#triggerElementId').click(function () {
     // this example sets string parameter as hardcoded string
     // change it to actual value by jQuery selector with val() or text() function
     var sCode = "XXX"; 

     var modelData = $('form').serialize(); 
     // or serializeArray() if you want to push additional data
     // if model contents should left unchanged, use 'var modelData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PrivateStudent))'

     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '@Url.Action("ShowStudent", "Student")',
         data: { studentCode: sCode, newPrivateStudent: modelData },
         success: function (result) {
             $('#targetResultElement').html(result);
         },
         error: function (xhr, status, error) {
             // error handling
         }
     });
});
```

Then setting controller action to retrieve key & serialized model contents as in example below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowStudent(string studentCode, PrivateStudentModel newPrivateStudent)
{
    // some actions

    return PartialView("_ShowStudent", viewModelName); // mention partial view & viewmodel name here
}
```